# SqlServer: what means precision 53?

Tags: sql-server

For example FLOAT type have default numeric precision `53`

```
SELECT * FROM sys.types
```

and TDS protocol sends precision `53`, but through OLEDB precision returns as `18`.
What exactly precision `53` means, it seems impossible to put as many decimal digits into 8 bytes? How OLEDB gets `18` from that number? I found `MaxLenFromPrecision` in Microsoft sources but this array up to precision `37` for numeric types only. FreeTDS have array up to `77` `tds_numeric_bytes_per_prec` but isn't similar with Microsoft's data and item by index `53` not `18` as OLEDB returns. By that is `53` is some virtual number while `18` real precision as described at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What exactly precision 53 means, it seems impossible to put as many decimal digits into 8 bytes?

Precision 53 is 53 bits.  8 bytes contain 64 bits.

A [double precision floating point number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) has 1 sign bit, 11 exponent bits, and 53 mantissa bits.

Comment: So Precision explained by Microsoft (18 by OLEDB) is decimal while 53 in bits? E.g. 10^18 = 2^53?

Comment: @user2091150: According to my calculator, 2^53 is more like 10^16.  53 bits of precision is the most you can have for a double precision floating point number.

Comment: Same 16, but maybe plus 1 more for sign http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008

Answer (score 1):

From BOL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx

> Where n is the number of bits that are used to store the mantissa of
>   the float number in scientific notation and, therefore, dictates the
>   precision and storage size. If n is specified, it must be a value
>   between 1 and 53. **The default value of n is 53**.

53 is the precision set at the database level if you don't explicitly set it when declaring your float data type.