# HSQLDB "precision or scale out of range" error when UCanAccess loads database

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, hsqldb, ucanaccess

I'm writing tools in java that connects to different access databases. I have a particular scenario that throws the following exception `-5592:UCAExc:::4.0.4 precision or scale out of range`

The exception is listed under HSQLDB exceptions:
`5592=42592 precision or scale out of range` (so I know who generates it)
and according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24248114/sqlserver-what-means-precision-53), [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377174/how-do-i-interpret-precision-and-scale-of-a-number-in-a-database/15520685#15520685), and the definitions in here, both precision and scale refer to characteristics of a double.

***The exception occurs only when I use ucanaccess to connect to an old mdb (pre-access 2003) trhough a frontend database with linked tables to the mdb. However, ucanaccess can connect to the old mdb directly without any issue.***

If I use the frontend in Access to modify the database it works fine, so I assume MS worked around the problem at least within Access.

My guess is that my ucanaccess connection is attempting to treat the database as a more modern one, being fooled by the front-end facade. But why this exception?

*Minimal Complete Verifiable Example:*
Here is a [minimal example to replicate the issue](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lAqdI9lKggMZOoFdZUB2T5KrR9xX0MzT) containing the offending mdb, is a gzip tarball which includes the following jar, the databases involved and a helpful readme file.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
String query= "SELECT nombre FROM encemp where cveemp=1";
    try {
        Connection frontEndToAccdb = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://FrontEndPointingToAccdb.accdb");            
        PreparedStatement statement = frontEndToAccdb.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
        if (resultSet.next()) System.out.println("Querying Accdb BackEnd through front end OK");            
        Connection directConnectionToMdb = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://X:/BackendOld.mdb");
        statement = directConnectionToMdb.prepareStatement(query);
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
        if (resultSet.next()) System.out.println("Querying mdb BackEnd directly OK");            
        //This is the one that will generate the exception
        Connection frontEndToMdb = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://FrontEndPointingToMdb.accdb");
        statement = frontEndToMdb.prepareStatement(query);
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
        if (resultSet.next()) System.out.println("Querying mdb BackEnd through front end OK");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.printf("%s:%s\n", ex.getErrorCode(),ex.getMessage());
    }
```

I've been struggling navigating the DatabaseMetaData and still have no clue why the offending mdb is generating the exception.

Comment: The OP wants to know what causes the error, specific to use of ucanaccess with ms-access databases via hsqldb. It is not a general questions about the meaning of precision and scale.

Comment: Exactly, thank you, precision and scale definitions are not too far off of what I originally understood, but why would this be an issue in this scenario?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] including download link(s) for sample .mdb and .accdb files that can be used to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Just added the example, the link was dead for a bit there, it should be working now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, this particular issue has nothing to do with DECIMAL numbers, or numeric columns at all. It is a bug in UCanAccess caused by a [bug in Jackcess](https://sourceforge.net/p/jackcess/bugs/151/) where the width of an Access_97 TEXT field is mis-reported as half of its actual width.

The database in question has a table with a column defined as TEXT(1), so Jackcess `getLengthInUnits` reports zero (because of integer division). UCanAccess tries to create a table in the HSQLDB backing database as

```sql
CREATE  CACHED TABLE DETCAD(SERIE VARCHAR(0), ...
```

and the `VARCHAR(0)` is triggering the "precision or scale out of range" exception.

jackcess-2.2.2.jar fixes the issue. You can use it to replace the jackcess-2.1.11.jar file that ships with UCanAccess 4.0.4.

Comment: Thank you, as an update: UCanAccess still throws the exception using jackcess-2.2.1

Comment: @LeedMx - There appears to be a typo in James' comment on the ticket. The patch was committed after 2.2.1 was released, so the fix will be included in 2.2.2.

Comment: And indeed it does!, Thank you, hope all open source endevours are filled with good will man like yourself sir!

Answer (score 3):

1. I took the liberty of updating your title.  Hopefully the new wording conveys what you mean.
2. Please do the following:

   a) Query the column definitions in question directly.  For example:

   ```
   // GetMetaData():
   try (ResultSet rsMD = connChem.getMetaData().getTables(null, null, null, null)) {
      while (rsMD.next()) {
          String tblName = rsMD.getString("TABLE_NAME");
          System.out.println(tblName);
      }
   }
   ```

   ... or ...

   ```
   -- SQL "select" from MSysObjects
   SELECT Name
   FROM MSysObjects
   WHERE Left([Name],1)<>"~"
   AND Left([Name],4)<>"MSys"
   AND Type In (1,4,6)
   ORDER BY Name;
   ```

   b) Compare the DB column definitions (above) with the corresponding Hibernate class members (for example, in your favorite IDE).

   c) Compare the results for an "old" .mdb (which "works") vs. a "new" .accdb.
3. Please update your post with the results.

Comment: Thanks for the renaming, so far the table information does not throw anything different between the two, will try to get column metadata and let you know

Answer (score 2):

Precision is the maximum total number of digits in a decimal. Scale is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point ([ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)). So if you had `decimal(20,10)` then it would be a decimal with 10 digits to the left, and 10 digits to the right of the decimal for a total of 20 digits. i.e. `1234567890.1234567890`. The maximum precision is 38, default is 18.

Examples

```
decimal(38,0): '12345678912345678912345678912345678900'
decimal(38,1): '1234567891234567891234567891234567890.0'
decimal(38,2): '123456789123456789123456789123456789.00'
decimal(38,3): '12345678912345678912345678912345678.900'
decimal(10,8): '12.12345678'
```

Comment: Or `1234567.89` has `precision: 9` and  `scale: 2`; `decimal(9,2)`.

Comment: I like your use of the numbers better @paulsm4